# How do I call a method in a ViewController class from one of its subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyinput

I wanted to pull up a keyboard without having to use a text field, so I subclassed UIToolbar and made it conform to the UIKeyInput protocol.  Based on my tests using simple NSLog printouts, I am successfully reading the key input from the user.  My problem is that I need the text that is typed into the keyboard to update a table view that is managed by the same view controller as my custom toolbar.  Basically my question is this:  If my update method is in my custom toolbar class, how do I tell it to update the table view?  Or, if my update method is in my view controller class, how do I make sure it gets called every time a key is pressed?

I tried to have my toolbar send a notification when a key was pressed like so:

```
- (void)insertText:(NSString *)text {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"keyPressed" object:self];
```

and subsequently listen for it with the view controller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(updateForKeyPressed:) name:@"keyPressed" object:nil];
```

...

```
- (void)updateForKeyPressed:(NSNotification *)note {
   [self update];
}
```

This didn't work, but that was no surprise as I got the idea from an online article, and I'm fairly certain I am doing it wrong.  I am pretty much button mashing at this point, and It would be sweet if someone could point me in the right direction.  As always, any help at all is greatly appreciated.  If anyone wants to see more of my code, let me know and I can post it up.

Comment: Just my guess [((MyViewController *)[[myToolBar superview] nextResponder]) update]

Comment: i misread your comment the first time, and overlooked the nextResponder call.  This successfully calls the update method, but the actions inside the method are not being performed.  I will update my question to reflect the real source of error.  thank you by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Using a notification should work fine. What have you done to debug your code? Are you sure that the notification is being posted? Are you sure that the view controller has registered itself with the notification center? Are you sure that `-updateForKeyPressed:` isnt' being called?

Delegation is another option that may be easier for you to set up and debug. Have the view controller set itself as the toolbar's delegate, and have the toolbar send a message to its delegate whenever its text changes, just as UITextView does.

The main idea to keep in mind is that your views shouldn't care about the view controller. The toolbar may happen to send messages to the view controller because the view controller happens to be its delegate, but it shouldn't rely on the fact that its delegate is a view controller.

Comment: What I realized after going back and trying anticyclop's way was that the notification being sent wasn't the problem at all.  The methods were (and are) being called.  The toolbar and the view controller are actually communicating fine.  The table view, however, is not responding to either the frame adjustment or the updates to the array.  On a side note, I didn't know you could do that for a toolbar since the toolbar doesn't appear to have a setDelegate method.  Thanks for the help--I always appreciate the insight.

Comment: @SamHazleton You said you subclassed UIToolbar, so you could easily add a delegate yourself.

Comment: @SamHazleton Declare a `delegate` property in your toolbar subclass and synthesize the accessors (or not). Optionally, declare a protocol with the method declarations that your toolbar delegate should implement. If you do, you can declare your delegate property as adopting that protocol: `@property(strong) id<MyProtocol> delegate;`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have the view controller conform to uikeyinput, then set the toolbar's delegate to the viewcontroller

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could do that.  Actually the notion is a bit disquieting considering the amount of work I have put in trying to do it this way.